# create form with placeholders for user input

Tags: html, forms

I was trying to create a survey form. I was wondering how to use html5 to create a form where it has placeholders for user input and after user click submit the survey form replaces the placeholders with the information provided by the user which can be printed later.

I am just a complete newbie so I'd appreciate if someone can explain to me like I'm five. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `placeholder` attribute to text/textarea elements. For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" />
```

The browser will output the form with the placeholder text. If you put text in it, the placeholder will hide.

This attribute only works on:

- Text inputs (E.g. text, search, url, tel, email, and password)
- Textarea's

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fpfznnj/2/

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field

The short hint is displayed in the input field before the user enters a value.
The placeholder attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, and password.

example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attribute used to show a small description of expected input (e.g. a sample value in expected format).

In html,placeholder attribute works for text, search, url, tel, email, and password.

examples for the above are,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" /><br />
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" /><br />
<textarea placeholder="Enter address"></textarea><br />
```

also we can style place holders using custom css classes or built in as,

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```